# How to insert data to MySQL then get those data after in order for the inserted data's primary id can be passed as foreign key for the next insertion?

Tags: mysql, reactjs

How to insert data to MySQL then get those data after in order for the inserted data's primary id can be passed as foreign key for the very next insertion in the same page in a functional component using React?

here is my code:

```
const [farminfo, setfarminfo] = useState([]);
 useEffect(() =>{
 Axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/farmprofileidget/${farm_name}`).then((response) => {
 setfarminfo(response.data);
    })
  }, [farm_name])
 var ea = farminfo[0]
 var farm_id_holder
 for (var key in ea) {
 if (ea.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
 if (key === "farm_id"){
 farm_id_holder = ea[key]
        }
    }
  }

const register = () => {
//first insertion
Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/farmpprofileadd", {farm_name: farm_name, size: size, soil_type: soil_type, description: description, title : title, main_owner: main_owner}); 
//second insertion
 
 Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/ownerprofileadd", {farm_id: owner_farm_id, owner_name: owner_name, owner_type: owner_type, contact_num: contact_num, educational_attainment: educational_attainment, position: position, job_desc: job_desc});
}
```

i only get `undefined` in my `farm_id_holder` variable
did i code it right? if there's something wrong and/or you have any suggestions, it will really be much appreciated. thank you.

Comment: I would suggest you send all that data in one call and then the code in `farmpprofileadd` would do both these processes and would have access to the Last_insert_id from the first insert

Comment: ^-- This, or create a stored procedure in MySQL that will do all the needed queries and pass it the values for both tables